# Many to One Matching Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, many-to-many

My apologies if this is a duplicate. I lack the Computer Science knowledge to know what to properly search for.

I need to find a matching algorithm. I've got a series of rooms, and a series of contents-for-rooms. The contents have a minimum size room in which they would fit - so some would happily fit in any room, some would only fit in one or two rooms. I'll also be having a maximum size for some of the rooms, but I assume that this only effects when I determine if the room would be suitable.

Assuming (though - this won't be guaranteed in my actual use) that there is a potential solution, how do I find the optimal allocation, such that each room is only used once and none of the contents are lacking a room?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem appears to be a [maximum bipartite matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs) problem. You could think of your problem as an undirected graph `G(V,E)` where the vertices `V` are the rooms and contents and the edges `E` are possible connections between rooms and contents:

1. The graph is bipartite. If we split the vertices into two sets, rooms and contents, there are no internal edges in each set.
2. An edge exists in the graph between `contents(i)` and `room(j)` if the room is big enough to hold the contents.

A maximum matching produces the maximum number of pairings between vertices in the two sets (i.e. rooms and contents), ensuring that each vertex is only used once. The matching is said to be "perfect" if all vertices are matched. There are a number of algorithms that can be used for such problems, potentially the fastest is the [Hopcroft-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft-Karp_algorithm) method.

You could also consider a further optimisation of your problem, in which you try to minimse the total wasted space in the rooms. In this case a "weight" would be associated to the edges defined above based on the difference between the areas of the contents and the rooms.
You would then seek a maximum weight maximum matching.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this as an http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem. You don't have matching numbers of things to be matched, but you can make up things for whichever side runs short first. If you make the cost for the made up things the same for every possible match, the minimum cost answer for a solution with made up things will also be the minimum cost answer for a solution without made up things which produces only a partial match, because the contribution of the made-up things to the cost is the same no matter how they are assigned.

(of course there may be a faster way to solve your specific problem - for instance if you only have one thing to match on one of the sides, just try it in every possible location).